# Stopping a while loop in the middle after time limit exceeded without continuing the loop to the end

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to stop a while loop in the middle and my code is:

```
import time

now = time.time()

future = now + 1.8

while time.time() < future: 
     time.sleep(2) # acts as instructions and code  
     print("Still in")

print("Now out")
```

I don't want it to print "Still in" as the time limit would have been exceeded but it continues the loop till the end. This is an example code.

Comment: its not how it works, program will consume all code inside while no matter what except if you break or encountered an error

Answer (score 0):

you can check the condition after `time.sleep()` and `break` out of `while` before reaching the rest of the block

```
import time

now = time.time()

future = now + 1.8

while True:
     time.sleep(2) # or any code that affects your condition 
     if time.time()>= future: #if this happens break the loop, if not continue 
         break
     print("Still in")

print("Now out")
```

Comment: Sorry, I should of said the time.sleep(2) is an example of instructions.

Comment: still, you can check your desired condition before the rest of the code and break out of the loop